# Start at boot apps not starting with custom launcher

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have created a basic launcher whose only jobs are to display a logo and display settings on keypress for kiosk type system. Two apps are supposed to start at boot. The launcher starts OK but the apps never start. The apps start Ok with default launcher.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.launcher"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <!-- The following two intent-filters are the key to set homescreen -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                this.DisplayWIFI();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void DisplayWIFI(){
        startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
    }
}
```

I have been stuck with this for quite a while and would appreciate any help.